SwiftUIでbody:someViewの中でForEachを使用してArray型に.insertを使うと起きるエラー
view内のForEachの中にarray型とinsertを書くと現れました。
insertを消して、Text("")のみにするとエラーは消えました。
私は、リストの中の値をfor文の中で一つずつ判断して、条件にあった値のみを、ForEachの外で作った配列に入れようとしました。
エラー:
Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)

エラーの日本語訳:
表現の診断を生成できませんでした。バグレポートを提出してください(https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)

コード:
import SwiftUI
var list = [0101,0202,0303,0404,0505]
struct ContentView: View {

    var body:some View{ <-ここにエラーが出る

        var list2 : [Int] = []

        ForEach(0..<list.count, id: \.self){index in
           Text("")
           if 0303 < list[index]{
               list2.insert(list[index], at : 0)
           }
    }
}

